# WC()->cart->add_to_cart() not working when cart page is loaded directly?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a product automatically to the cart, whenever the user goes to the cart page.

I have added the following code in cart.php:

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
```

When I try to simply visit the cart page by entering the url - example.com/cart/ , then the product above does not get added, however, when I add another product to cart on live site and click 'view cart', this particular product that I have added above via code, also gets added to the cart (I tried both, as logged in user and as guest).

I did try to set session cookie on before the above code but that didn't work either:

```
WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_product_to_cart' );
function add_product_to_cart() {
//check if we are on cart page
    if (is_cart()) {
        $product_id = 69; //replace with your own product id
        $found = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->get_id() == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }
}
```